# How can I desctructure items out of an object that is returned from a React hook using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks

I have a component that needs to tap into the React Router query params, and I am using the `use-react-router` hook package to access them.

Here is what I am wanting to do:

```
import React from "react;
import useReactRouter from "use-react-router";


const Foo = () => {
  const { id } = useReactRouter().match.params;

  return (
    <Bar id={id}/>
  )
}
```

The issue is that this throws the following error in VS Code, and at compile time: 
`Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)`

I have found that if I refactor my code like so:
`const id = match.params["id"]`, I do not get the error, but I feel like this is not the correct approach for some reason. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The solution was to include angle brackets between the hook's name and the parenthesis, like so:

```
const { match } = useRouter<{ id: string }>();
const { id } = useRouter<{ id: string }>();
```

Or if you prefer nested destructuring:

```
const { match: { params: id } } = useRouter<{ id: string }>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give default value to `params`

```
const { id } = useReactRouter().match.params || {id: ""};
```

It may be possible that `params` to be null at initial level

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, and unfortunately, it's still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The code is insufficient.
However, at first glance,

```
//  right way
const { history, location, match } = useReactRouter()

//  in your case
const { match: { params : { id } } } = useReactRouter()

// or
const { match } = useReactRouter()
const { id } = match.params
```

now, try to console the value first.
Also, please try to pass the props to a functional component from it's container, since it's more logical.

From your comment below, i can only assume you solved it. Also, it's recommended to handle possible undefined values when you use it.

```
{ id && id }
```

However, the first step should've been consoling whether it has value in it,

```
console.log('value xyz', useReactRouter())
```

Comment: That is actually the way I was doing it before, but it still throws an `ERROR TS2339`  anytime I try to access the id from match.params. I'll make a quick edit to be a bit more specific on what I am trying to accomplish.